# Can no longer build Ionic 3 (angular) app using node 12 as of May 2023

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have to maintain a legacy Ionic3 App. (Yes I know it's out of date, we are in the process of porting it to Ionic7)

Ionic3 requires node-sass which isn't supported > Node12

It was building fine until today when I now get the error:
`ERR: Your Node.js version is v12.19.0. Node.js 12 reached end-of-life on 2022-04-30 and is no longer supported. Please update to the latest Node LTS version.`

We use NVM (0.39.3) to manage our node version. Up to today we have just swapped back to node12 using NVM

One of my co-workers was able to build today on node v12 until he changed to v18 and then back to v12 and he is now getting the same issue.

I thought it might be the new Ionic cli so I swapped back from Ionic CLI 7 -> to 6.18.1. Same problem.

We haven't changed our NVM version.

The only thing I can think that has changed in the last couple of days is I installed the latest apple rapid security update.

We now can't build the old Ionic3 app and need to push an update out so are stuck.

Does anyone have suggestions.

We can't figure out what has caused this issue:

- nvm
- ionic cli
- mac os

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, fixed it....

1. Open a new terminal
2. Uninstall node 12 `nvm uninstall 12`
3. Install node 12 again `nvm install 12`

Now it works - not sure why ‍♂️

Comment: Hope you can upgrade soon as Node 12 isn't even mentioned on the [long term support page](https://nodejs.dev/en/about/releases/).

Comment: @tadman yup, we're on Ionic7 and node 18 now :) Just had to do one last build of the legacy app on node12

Answer (score 1):

Just if the uninstalling and re-installing didn't work with someone as it didn't with me,
I tried removing ionic and cordova globally then re-installing using

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm uninstall -g cordova
```

then

```
npm install -g ionic@3.20.1
```

replace 3.20.1 with your appropriate version for sure.