# Can't build Ionic 5 (angular) app using Node.js v12.22.12 or v12.22.6

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ionic-framework, nvm

I have a really old app that I need to run and I'm using nvm so I can use older versions of node.js and ionic. They're really old dependencies and I just need it to run in a dev environment.

The error I get from Git Bash is:

> $ ionic serve
> ERR: Your Node.js version is v12.22.12. Node.js 12 reached end-of-life on 2022-04-30 and is no longer supported. Please update to the latest Node LTS version.

How can I work around this error? They are a bunch of dependencies which would not accept later Node.js versions.

I found this similar problem:
[Can no longer build Ionic 3 (angular) app using node 12 as of May 2023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76211553/can-no-longer-build-ionic-3-angular-app-using-node-12-as-of-may-2023)
But all the answers did not help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Installed node.js version 16 (nvm install 16) and it seems to be running fine for now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).